# How to Measure in-app behavior and tie it back to the Ad Campaign in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

We have launched an ad campaign using Facebook Ad Manager for our app. At the same time, we are using Facebook events to record different event across the app. Till now we found out that we can attribute app installs and launches from the Facebook ads using the deferred deep linking.

We are wondering if there is a way to measure how many users are clicking on a specific ad who downloaded our app, then track the (post-download data) Events/Metrics that those users had performed in our app (Events: such as an account sign-up) and (Metrics: such as LTV).

Shortly, 
How can we track the following:
- Click to app activation tracking
- ROI measurement
- Measure in-app behavior (account sign-ups, in app purchases) and tie it back to the Ad that where the user came from, so we can refine our acquisition efforts.

If not, Is there any 3rd parties that ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using Deferred Deep Linking as a reporting mechanism. It's a decent first cut at a proxy, but we can do better, and address your other goals at the same time. Step 1: Implement [App Events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events). The basic SDK implementation will send an Activation/Install event; add another event when your customer's LTV increases (e.g. a purchase) with a value equal to the **incremental** LTV.

When you create your ad, make sure to track your app's events.

Then when your campaign is live, go to Ads Manager and view your campaign. Click the Columns dropdown, then Performance. Select "Total Conversions Value". You can change the click/view attribution window (1, 7 or 28 days) using the link in the bottom right of the dialog. If you want click-through only, leave the view window unselected. Note that there is often substantial value delivered by people who viewed but did not click on your ads, so I recommend looking at both even if click-through is your primary metric at present.

Also worth mentioning: Implementing App Events will allow you to optimize your campaigns for in-app purchases, which is likely to drive a substantial boost in your ad performance.

If you're interested in doing more of the work on your side, you can add a tracking parameter to your deep link, store the user information on your systems and correlate it with LTV. It's a lot more work and doesn't allow for view-through attribution but the option is available.

Lastly, it's worth pointing out some drawbacks to using Deferred Deep Linking for attribution:

1. They are tied to a device, not a person. App Events are tied to people and can capture cross-device activity, including value.
2. They do not allow for optimization (as App Events do).
3. They do not allow for audience creation. In contrast, you can create retargeting and lookalike audiences based on App Events.
4. They do not capture view-through activity (App Events do).
5. They do not have flexible attribution windows, as App Events do.